# Want to add build number in my Maven created JAR file

Tags: maven, devops

I want to add CI build number in my Maven created jar file.
now my JAR file name is " XXX_5.0.0.jar" , but I want to create " XXX_5.0.0-100.jar" .

100 is the Build number from CI pipeline.

Comment: What kind of information can be the build number give any consumer of your jar? Usually if you are currently developing things the version is like `5.0.0-SNAPSHOT` if you want a reproducible state which means to create a release which is marked `5.0.0` ...

Comment: What is your CI platform? Jenkins? Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59160318/how-to-add-build-number-from-jenkins-to-jar-file

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238944/controlling-maven-final-name-of-jar-artifact?

Comment: yes its working fine. @pleft , used sh'''
                mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version
                mvn versions:set -DnewVersion='${env.TAG_NAME}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}'
            '''

Comment: Please read "[ask]".